# Setting up a query to look at a specific index of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm Having trouble with setting up a query - it is an array of objects, and I'm looking at a specific index. So my Schema has a field that is an array of objects:

```
{userID: ObjectID,
someArray: [{foo: "bar"},{bar: "foo"}]}
```

I'd like to return either all records where the first element in SomeArray has a non-empty object or where someArray does not contain null.

Ive tried using:

```
 db.find({someArray: {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}} })
```

however often someArray has a null object in it so that doesn't work.
If all fails I could potentially cache the entire collection and filter with raw javascript though that might not be the ideal way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, I suggest using the $ne (not-equal) helper

The implementation in your case:

```
db.find({someArray: {$ne: null})
```